# Why my Association using Factory Bot is not working?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, factory-bot

I am using Factory Bot to specify the association between two models, **vehicles** and **documents**. A vehicle **has_many** documents and a document **belongs_to** vehicle.
They are as it follows :

```
#spec/factories/vehicles.rb

    FactoryBot.define do
      factory :vehicle do
        user { nil }
        vehicle_model
        vehicle_color
        vehicle_type { FactoryBot.build(:vehicle_type, name:"Terrestre") }
        vehicle_year
        identifier { 'MyString' }
        status { :active }
        category
    
      end 
    end

#spec/factories/documents.rb
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :document do
    vehicle { nil }
    status { 'valid_file' }
    name { 'CRLV' }
  
  end
end
```

In this project I have a role **driver** that will need of an active vehicle document(this is the association that I want to build) to ride.
I inserted byebug in the point of the code that I want to check. Firstly I checked if the vehicle is activated, so I typed : **driver.active_vehicle**, and I received :

> #<Vehicle id: 2, user_id: 2, identifier: "MyString", created_at: "2020-07-20 16:57:22", updated_at: "2020-07-20 16:57:22", status:
> "active", category_id: 2, vehicle_model_id: 3, vehicle_color_id: 2,
> vehicle_type_id: 6, vehicle_year_id: 2>

Secondly I checked if the association is happening, so I typed : **driver.active_vehicle.documents** and I received the following return :

**#<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy []>**

It's empty. Why this happened and how can I fix it ?

Comment: OK ... in response to your rewritten question, your `documents` association is empty because you don't create any in your factory. You should implement your `with_document` trait to do this in an `after(:create)` callback.

Answer (score 0):

Your factory isn't called `vehicles` it's called `vehicle`.

Use it like this:

```
FactoryBot.create(:vehicle, :with_document)
```

Also, you added your `:with_document` trait to the `document` factory, rather than the `vehicle` factory as per your usage.

Comment: Thanks for answering me!. Well, I tried this, but I received the same error : ArgumentError:
  Factory not registered: vehicle

Comment: Have you tried it after also fixing the trait you're calling so it's defined within the right factory? Probably worthwhile fixing everything, and then updating your question with the correct code and any new errors you're getting. At this point I'd just be guessing.

Comment: I'll reformulate the question and the code, so probably it's gonna be easier for you to think about the problem ok ?